# android HTML parsing using JSOUP

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I have a task which says I need to parse a webpage via my android app. I search on the internet for a good solution and finally found out JSOUP library could help me out.

I have tried two tutorials.
one of them is :

http://www.radixjob.com/2013/12/android-html-parsing-tutorial-jsoup.html

the problem above app code link is that when I click on search button after entering an item. the Dialogue keeps moving endlessly.

even with the other solution which i tried, it has the same problem.

I am  following the exact method as mentioned in the link. Plz guide me where I am making a mistake.

Thanking in advance :)

Comment: does your LogCat show any error/exception?